# Datatable in AngularJs is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring, datatable

Datatable used in angularjs is not working properly. 
[You can see in the image there are 38 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlKiw.jpg)
[When I click on Number 2 in data table pagination, it shows as Showing 11 to 20 of 38 items, but the records in the table are still 1 to 10, you can see in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNJtL.jpg)
Here is my code:

```
<tbody data-ng-if="reviewers.length">
<tr data-ng-repeat="reviewer in reviewers">
<td align="center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-ng-click="getTaskInfo(reviewer.taskId)">{{reviewer.gtaskId}}</a></td>
<td align="center">{{reviewer.serviceName}}</td>
<td align="center">{{reviewer.projectSubject}}</td>
<td align="center">{{reviewer.taskCreatedDate | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</td>
<td align="center">{{reviewer.taskEndDate | date : 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Code in controller.js is

```
$scope.searchkey='';
    $scope.getReviewerTaskDetails = function(currentPageIndex){

        ReviewerService.getAllReviewerTaskCount().then(function(response){
            $scope.taskscount = response.data;
        });

        ReviewerService.getPendingTaskCount().then(function(response){
            $scope.pendingcount = response.data;
        });

        ReviewerService.getCompletedTaskCount().then(function(response){
            $scope.completedcount = response.data;
        });

        ReviewerService.getDeletedTaskCount().then(function(response){
            $scope.deletedCount = response.data;
        });


        ReviewerService.getReviewerTaskCount($scope.searchkey).then(function(response){
            $scope.paginationIndex = [];
            $scope.pageFullIndex = response.data;
            console.log($scope.pageFullIndex);
            var pagesize = Math.ceil(($scope.pageFullIndex)/($scope.recordsPerPage));
            for(var i=1;i<=pagesize;i++){
                $scope.paginationIndex.push(i);
            }
        });

        ReviewerService.getReviewersTaskByIndex(currentPageIndex,$scope.recordsPerPage,$scope.searchkey).then(function(response){
            $scope.reviewers= response.data;
            $scope.pageStartIndex = ((currentPageIndex-1)*($scope.recordsPerPage))+1;
            $scope.pageEndIndex = (($scope.pageStartIndex)+response.data.length)-1;
            $scope.currentPageIndex = currentPageIndex;
            $scope.selected = currentPageIndex;

        });
    };
```

Even some times data table is not loading properly and not showing total records it shows as showing 0 to 0 of 0, and no pagination numbers, and no search gets works.

Where as records per page if I choose 100 then all records gets displayed on the page. Can some help me here fixing this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom directive for pagination.

https://github.com/Crawlink/material-angular-paging